# Regex to verify first and last character

Tags: php, regex

I need to verify in php that a string should not start or end with a hyphen `(-)`. The allowed characters are `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and a hyphen anywhere in the middle of the string.

My this regex

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$/
```

Verifies the occurrence of allowed character expect the condition that the string should not start or end with the hyphen. How do I achieve this? I new to regex.

Comment: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9_](.*)[a-zA-Z0-9_]$/` A rough approach.

Comment: You have an underscore in your example but you don't mention it being allowed?

Comment: @MichaelRushton : My error! Updated the regex.

Comment: Cool. See my answer below. Some of the others include the underscore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be what you need.

```
/^[a-z0-9]+([a-z0-9-]+[a-z0-9])?$/iD
```

Notice the `D` modifier. Without it the expression would match a string that ends in a new line. See here: http://blog.5ubliminal.com/posts/surprises-of-php-regexp-the-d-modifier/. Also, I've used the `i` modifier to not have to use `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. Keeps the expression shorter.

Here's a couple of examples. As the input string ends in a new-line, it should fail, but without the `D` modifier, even with the `$` anchor, it passes:

```
// Outputs: int(1)
var_dump(preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]+([a-z0-9-]+[a-z0-9])?$/i', "aBc-d\n"));

// Outputs: int(0)
var_dump(preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]+([a-z0-9-]+[a-z0-9])?$/iD', "aBc-d\n"));
```

Comment: Thumbs up for that D modifier!

Answer (score 4):

Use negative [look ahead and look behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to achieve this

```
^(?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?<!-)$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30h2u)

`^(?!-)` is a negative look ahead assertion, ensures that it does not start with a dash

`(?<!-)$` is a negative look behind assertion, ensures that it does not end with a dash

The advantage of the lookarounds is that they do not match a character, but just defining an assertion, that means your string can also have a length of 1, where the solution with explicitly requiring a non dash as first and last character makes a min length of 2.

Btw. `a-zA-Z0-9_` is a predefined class `\w` so if you also want to allow the underscore you can change to:

```
^(?!-)[\w-]+(?<!-)$
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/
```

"One or one of anything except the hyphen, then any number of anything including hyphen, then one or more anything except the hyphen".

EDIT: This will fail if the string is one character long. Sorry about that. But you get the idea... Split it into sub-regex's.

Comment: Well, my string is made of 3 characters minimum, so that't not a problem :)

Answer (score 1):

> Verifies the occurrence of allowed character expect the condition that the string should not start or end with the hyphen. How do I achieve this? I new to regex.

Put simply: `~^[^-][a-z0-9-]+[^-]$~` should match. It says the first character can not be a `-`, then it says the middle part can only contain [a-z0-9-], and then it says the last character can't be a '-'. That said, you can also do this with substr, I don't think you actually need a regular expression.

With substr:

```
<?php
$valid = ((substr($str, 0, 1) != '-') && (substr($str, -1) != '-'));
```

*EDIT*: Didn't read the alphanumeric plus hyphen part, included it in the regex.

Comment: you forgot about a-z0-9 inside

Comment: What about the special characters in the middle of the string? the above snippet will just take care about the first and last character not being a hyphen.

Comment: Your regex `~^[^-][a-z0-9-]+[^-]$~` would match `$Foo;`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) method.
something like:

```
if ((substr($str, 0, 1) != '-') && (substr($str, strlen($str)) != '-')){
```

It may also has a function similar to `charAt` in javascript but I don't remember it right now. (That will get you a more readable code)

Comment: What about the special characters in the middle of the string? the above snippet will just take care about the first and last character not being a hyphen.

Comment: @Rahul Well you already have a regular expression for that, so just combine the tow in a way that makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a regular expression per-se but works according to your requirements:

```
if(
   ctype_alnum($str[0]) && 
   ctype_alnum($str[strlen($str)-1]) && 
   strpos(substr($str, 1, strlen($str-1)), '-') !== false
) {
   echo 'a match';
}
```